# Why does my add() method in LinkedList not working?

Tags: java, linked-list

I just implement `add()` method in my `Linkedlist` but it does not really work. I think "current = new Node(node.data);" makes the object point to a new object instead of update the original one but I don't know how to solve it. Is there any way that I can update this node properly? Please help, thanks.

```
class Node{
    int data;
    Node next; 
    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
    Node(int data, Node next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
class LinkedList{
    protected Node head;
    protected int size;
    LinkedList(){};

    void add(int data)
    {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        }else {
            Node current = head;
            while(current != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current = new Node(node.data);
        }
        size++;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        Node current = head;
        String result = "";
        while(current != null) {    
            result += current.data +"->";
            current = current.next;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you even using any of this code?  I don't see a `main()` method or any other point of entry.

Comment: void add(int data)
{
 Node node = new Node(data);

 if (head == null) {

  head = node;
 }
 else {
  Node tail= head;// I renamed the current to tail

  while(tail!= null && tail.next !== null) {
   tail= tail.next;
  }

  tail.next = node;
 }

 size++;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Your problem lies here

```
while(current != null) {
... }

current = new Node(node.data);
```

That creates a new node, which should sit on the very **end** of your list. But you only assign the new instance to a **local** variable ... which then gets lost, because the method ends.

Instead, you have to change your loop until you find the **last** entry that isn't null, so that `current.next == null`. To then simply go:

```
current.next = new Node(node.data);
```

Comment: GhostCat Hi, I don't understand your logic. Can you put it in a simple way? Do you mean I have to find one element before current?

Comment: @crazymind Just look at your condition (in the while loop loop!) and mine, in the last paragraph. And then take a piece of paper and write down what your code is doing. Use boxes to denote objects, and arrows pointing to "next". Seriously: banging your head against the wall until you get it is an essential part of the learning curve here. We have all been there ...  in other words: try to understand each step of your code. What happens, where does information go to, and so on.

Comment: GhostCat Carey Brown = GhostCat??!

Comment: GhostCat  create a new node hold old node which is not null (before getting out of loop), then use that node.next to update?

Comment: GhostCat else {
   Node current = head;
   Node holder = null;
   while(current != null) {
    
    if (current != null) {
     holder = current;
    }
    current = current.next;
    
    
   }
   
   
   holder.next = new Node(node.data);
   
    

   
  } works, thanks

Comment: @crazymind You should avoid putting code into comments ;-) ... but I am glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

In a LinkedList, the values are added to the top per say. It is not like adding to an array. So when you add a new Node, instead of trying to add it to the end, you would just add it as the new head element.

It is as easy as:

```
public void add(T item) {

    Node<T> next = new Node<>(item, head);
    this.head = next;
    size++;

}
```

If you want to restrict your LinkedList to only int, then you can replace T with int.

I hope this helps

Comment: I think the add method should add the new item to the end instead of the begin, so we should find the tail and then set next field of the tail to the new item.

Comment: @No Em I'm sorry, that is just not how a LinkedList works.